# Identifying an openGL 3d model

Tags: opengl, 3d

I currently have an application that uses openGL in order to render a 3d model of a car.
I would like to change the car models but I have no clue what format my application uses.
The current format of the working 3d model is directory that holds one xml file, 3 .tga files, and arround 40 .dat files.
I am a backend software developper and I have never done any 3d modeling.
I would be very gratefull if anyone could enlight me on what format this is and how I could export a blender format into this format.

Comment: [`.tga` is an image file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) but `.xml` can contain all sorts of things and `.dat` is an extension for arbitrary binary data files, so there isn't a whole lot to go on here. Can you post a portion of the `.xml` file? That will give a lot more clues.

Comment: You're looking for a whole bunch of floating point numbers. Won't be in the tga files. Could be stored in text or binary. Most likely there is also a separate whole bunch of integers. Those are the two big things to identify. Vertex and index data

Answer (score 1):

It could be the X3D format, but without more information I couldn't be sure.
You could try reading [A comparison of 3D file formats](https://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:462098/FULLTEXT01.pdf).
If you're in a unix/linux environment you could try file.
[file(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file).
Finally you could trade a game/engine data extraction tool
[Game Extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gameextractor/)
[Game Extractor(might be the same software)](https://github.com/wattostudios/GameExtractor)
[Extraction tools](https://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Extraction_tools)